How do spark workers send their results back?
I have the following setup:

Kubernetes
One pod running as a spark master
One pod running as a spark worker
From my laptop, I port forward into the Kubernetes cluster to the spark master
On my laptop from the CLI, I run a Python spark shell pyspark --master spark://localhost:7077
spark.range(1).count() is my test command

In the stderr of the worker, I see an exception that the worker is trying to connect back to my laptop to send some something.
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to p02v2vthj3d3d7.attlocal.net/<unresolved>:49288

Is the spark worker trying to send results back directly to my laptop? For some reason I imagined that data would traverse through the master before coming back to my laptop.
Is the correct solution for this to instead of using my laptop as the origin for pyspark/spark-submit, to use a different container within the cluster as the originator? Or perhaps is there some setting I can flip to stop workers to reach out to my laptop and instead work through the master?
Thanks,

Spark uses several different network hops to collect results. This answer is for Mesos, but I think k8s is similar https://stackoverflow.com/a/56486271/2308683

So your k8s is a local cluster? You use something like minikube to create it?

@Jonathan it's on AWS EKS
